# Why Clion Debug tool can not find my file even my file in cmake-build -debug folder?

Tags: c++, debugging, clion

Clion debug tool does not working when I try to reach a text file. I put it in c-make-build-debug folder but it still can not find my file.

I need reach a text file for my c++ project in Clion. I appended this file to  c-make-build-debug folder however, when ı debug my code ı got an "no such file or directory error. When I run my code  everything work well. What is the reason of this problem?
Here is the output :  C:/Users/user1/Desktop/AS1203/PA1_template/PA1_template/src/cmake-build-debug/src.exe: No such file or directory.